# PyQt5 QColor conversion from HSV

Tags: pyqt5

I am doing a HSV color picker for Krita that has PyQt5.
I wanted to make use of the QColor class to take care of display color conversions, however i am not able to convert the color with success.

I used this color selector as a reference for my output:

```
https://www.google.com/search?sxsrf=ACYBGNR9_2R1jGyxkqbdM8DVZfU-8hogYg%3A1583142187803&source=hp&ei=K9VcXqrKLuyMlwTorLH4Dg&q=color+picker+hex&oq=color+picker&gs_l=psy-ab.3.0.35i39l2j0l8.3060.6761..8026...2.0..0.310.1102.11j3-1......0....1..gws-wiz.....10..35i362i39j0i10.C-faeoukSfM
```

a random color of choice was:

```
HEX=(#eb4034)
HSV=(7, 78, 92)
```

When I try to convert it with this code:

```
from PyQt5.QtGui import QColor

hsv = QColor.fromHsv(7,78,92,255)
color = str(hsv.redF()*255)+" | "+str(hsv.greenF()*255)+" | "+str(hsv.blueF()*255)

print(str( color ))
```

my output is:

```
92.0 | 67.14007782101167 | 63.85992217898833
[Finished in 0.168s]
```

instead of:

```
235, 64, 52
```

How do I input a HSV color into the QColor and then convert it to RGB for display purposes?

thank you in advance

Comment: Besides the correct answers already provided, remember that conversion between RGB and HSV/L is not always absolute, as there are different methods to achieve that. As your example shows, with the given #eb4034 your Hue value you have is 7°, while Google picker returns 4° and QColor.getHsv shows 3 (because it rounds down 3.93). Also, float values might not be consistent (for the reason written before and due to floating point limitations), especially between from[Format]F and to[Format]F.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reference values for the HVS color (i.e. `(7, 78, 92)`) are in units degree, percent, and percent, respectively, whereas `QColor.fromHSV` expects values in the range 0-255. To convert the reference values to something that can be used by `QColor` you could try something like this

```
HSV=(7, 78, 92)
hue, sat, value = HSV
hue = int(hue*255/360)
sat = int(sat*255/100)
value = int(value*255/100)

hsv = QColor.fromHsv(hue, sat, value, 255)
color = str(hsv.redF()*255)+" | "+str(hsv.greenF()*255)+" | "+str(hsv.blueF()*255)

print(str( color ))

# output: 234.0 | 64.42023346303502 | 52.307392996108945
```

Comment: is  there a better way to just input HSV values directly into QColor without changing its range? I used "fromHasv()" just because it seemed like the better option until now.

Comment: You could write your own function: `def fromHsv(h, s, v): return QColor.fromHsv(int(h*255/360), int(s*255/100), int(v*255/100), 255)`

Comment: I was inputting (360,100,100) range values so I placed sat and value as: sat or value=(input/100)*255 to change the range and it worked

Answer (score 1):

You can use the getRgb() method to get a tuple with the values:

```
>>> hsv = QColor.fromHsv(7,78,92,255)
>>> hsv.getRgb()
(92, 67, 64, 255)
```

You will notice the values are different than what you expected, this is because the color hex #eb4034 is not the same as HSV (7, 78, 92).

```
>>> hsv.name()
'#5c4340'
>>> QColor('#eb4034').getHsv()
(3, 199, 235, 255)
```

Make sure you are using the correct HSV values.

Comment: I did not know you could use it like that. thank you so much for showing me.